# Compare two ArrayLists

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net

I am trying to compare 2 `ArrayList`s without success.

What I have is this:

```
Dim array_1 As New ArrayList()
Dim array_2 As New ArrayList()
Dim final_array As New ArrayList()
```

In `array_1` and `array_2` I have:

```
array_1({10, 20}, {11, 25}, {12, 10})
array_2({10, 10}, {11, 20})
```

And in `final_array` I want to get:

```
array_1(1) - array_2(1)
```

to get this:

```
final_array({10, 10}, {11, 5}, {12, 10}
```

How can I create code to do this correctly?  Here is my attempt:

```
For Each element In array_1
    For Each element_2 In array_2
        If element(0) = element_2(0) Then
            final_array.Add({element(0), element(1) - element_2(1)})
        Else
            final_array.Add({element(0), element(1)})
        End If
    Next
Next
```

This code does not do what I want.

Comment: ArrayList accepts an object, does your object have 2 integer properties? Looks to me like you are better off with a Dictionary (key based access).

Comment: Dictionary seems to be a better fit, and I don't think you want to compare but substract elements of two array right?

Answer (score 0):

You should not join the two arrays like that. Basically, for each element in the first array, you iterate the whole second array.

So, in pseudo-code (sorry, my VB skills are awful) it should look like this:

```
let end = min(array1.lenght, array2.length)
for i = 0 to end
  if array1[i].first = array2[i].first
  then final_array[i] = {array1[i].first, array1[i].second - array2[i].second}
  else final_array[i] = array1[i]

// in case array1 is bigger than array2 you need to copy its last elements
for j = i to array1.length
  final_array[j] = array1[j]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Except LINQ function:

[From the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

```
    ' Create two arrays of doubles. 
    Dim numbers1() As Double = {2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5}
    Dim numbers2() As Double = {2.2}

    ' Select the elements from the first array that are not 
    ' in the second array. 
    Dim onlyInFirstSet As IEnumerable(Of Double) = numbers1.Except(numbers2)

    Dim output As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    For Each number As Double In onlyInFirstSet
        output.AppendLine(number)
    Next 

    ' Display the output.
    MsgBox(output.ToString())

    ' This code produces the following output: 
    ' 
    ' 2 
    ' 2.1 
    ' 2.3 
    ' 2.4 
    ' 2.5
```